# SharePoint Webpart deserialize error

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, serialization

I am getting a random web part error, it works one refresh and then not the next:

> **Web Part Error**: One of the properties of the web part has an
>   incorrect format.  Windows SharePoint
>   services cannot deserialize the Web
>   Part.  Check the format of the
>   properties and try again.

The web parts have been on the site for a long time, and I have checked Micorsoft Support, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826786 .  And it is not a permision error becuase it has been this way for a long time.  The only thing changed in regards to webparts was going into Site settings > Web Parts > New and selected some webparts that were not in the list and I think I also Checked the ones that are having this random error and clicked "Populae Gallery".  Any body have a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but try doing this:

Go the central administration

> operations 
>   service accounts 
>   Web application pool (radio button) 
>   webservice (drop down); select windows sharepoint services web app 
>   application pool (second drop down); select the site that the problems occurs on e.g. home_port_80 
>   user name (text field): type in the account info you have used during sharepoint post installation configuration 
>   password: at last type in the password.

hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

This could also be because of insufficient disk space on the server where SharePoint is hosted. http://www.sharepointblogs.com/vipul/archive/2006/09/25/webpart-error-due-to-space-crunch.aspx Check the available disk space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: We also had this issue as well as search was failing, and there appeared to be no disk space issues.  I performed an IISRESET /noforce on all three servers in our farm.  The iis reset of the last one failed so I did a more forceful reset and everything started working again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried rebooting your server. I have just recovered from this exact problem. One of my frontend servers ran out of disk space yesterday and I recovered 10Gb of it, however this didn't rectify the error I was receiving when trying to view or add page viewer webparts until I rebooted it. All is perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that can cause this is an "undocumented feature" in SPD that splits the Web Part properties across two lines, like this:

```
<FrameType>
None</FrameType>
```

Just removed the line break, like this:

```
<FrameType>None</FrameType>
```

and everything started working again ...